# Installing PHP intl extension

Tags: php, laravel

I am running my **Laravel 8** app using free plan in **Heroku**.

However, the issue was I'm getting prompted with an error of:

> Class 'NumberFormatter' not found

Upon searching I have read a solution to *install php intl extension*. Can I have a guide on how exactly would I do this ? Thank you so much.

Comment: Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions

Comment: Install `extension=ext/php_intl.dll` or update php.ini settings by uncommenting `extension=ext/php_intl.dll`

Comment: If you don't have access to these files then check with Heroku support.

Comment: Thanks guys! I have it worked and running. I've spent minutes trying to figure out not to f things up, didn't know it was this easy. Thank you so much again! :)

Comment: @jade: You say thanks on the site by leaving your solution as the answer if no-one else did. Just commenting saying thanks and not writing how it's done is more or less taken as a punch in the face. I'm pretty sure you did not want to express that (yes you can still answer your own question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have explicitly enabled the extension via `composer.json` like so:

(Note: use "*" as the version selector.)

```
{
    "require": {
        "ext-intl": "*",
    }
}
```

then run `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this in php.ini

extension=ext/php_intl.dll

Or (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
apt-get install php7.0-intl
```