# Configuration to use php intl package in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, localization, collation, intl

I have followed the first answer solution of this question [Installing PHP intl extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012122/installing-php-intl-extension) , so I have introduced in composer the line `"ext-intl": "*",` and run `composer update` (everything went smooth), but when I try to use within my controller `$collator = locale_get_default();` I receive the following answer:

**Error
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\locale_get_default()**

I do not know how to link my code to the **ext-intl** package that I have added to the composer configuration.

Thanks in advance for your help.

--

Thank you for your answer Sergio. I have realized that in the web server the **php-intl** is operative, so I only need to install it in my development environment (XAMPP over OSx: I will find out and come back). But now a new question has came out, thus:

Even in my web server (where **php-intl** is running) it seems that there is no effective link between the **php** and the **Laravel** levels. I have arrived to this conclusion (that surprises me), because if I make a change in the locale with php, it seems not to take place in Laravel Level. Example:

If I run the following (being the server configuration "en_US"):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.utf8");
$collator = locale_get_default();
dd($collator);
```

**the output is "es_ES"**, but if I run:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.utf8");
dd(App::currentLocale());
```

**the output is "en"**.

By the other side, if I run:

```
App::setLocale('es');
dd(App::currentLocale());
```

**the output is "es"**. But if I run:

```
App::setLocale('es');
$collator = locale_get_default();
dd($collator);
```

**the output is " en_US_POSIX "**.

There is something that I am not understanding here! Do I have to change both levels at the same time when a localization change requested by the user takes place, so all functions related in both levels (PHP: **uasort()**, Laravel: **Collection->sort(SORT_LOCALE_STRING)**) work synchronized? This seems to be a potential source of inconsistencies! (?)

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Extension must be installed on server side, eg. sudo apt-get install php-intl . If you are sure you installed it, check if it is enabled, you can do it checking phpinfo https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php